# javascript gallery not displaying main image when thumbnails clicked

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm wanting to create a gallery which displays a main image when the thumbnails are clicked. When clicked the thumbnails rather than altering the image in the webpage take the user to the file where the image is kept and display it in the top right corner.

No idea why this is happening ? Any suggestions where I'm going wrong and how to fix this ?

```
<img id="veiwer" src="images/motorbike-girl.jpg" />
<div id='thumbs'>
   <a href='images/chicks.jpg' onclick="gallery(this);"><img src='images/chicks-
   thumb.jpg'/></a>
   <a href='images/motorbike-girl.jpg' onclick="gallery(this);"><img 
   src='images/motorbike-girl-thumb.jpg'/></a>                                                
   <a href='images/yamaha-thumb.jpg' onclick="gallery(this);"><img              
   src='images/yamaha.jpg'/></a>    
</div>


         function gallery(change) {

          document.getElementById('viewer').src = change.href;
         }
```

Comment: You mispelled "viewer" to "veiwer" in your HTML...

Comment: You're right. I've changed it but the same problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the default behavior of the anchor tag : by default, when you click a link, you get to the page/document it's pointing to. 
So, in your javascript you would need to tell "Don't run the default behavior, only what I want to do". It's done through the `preventDefault()` method of the event.

cfr [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3URP/) for a working example, where I removed also the inline javascript (= `onclick` attribute).

Comment: Although not best practice if I wanted to use inline javascript would it look something like this ?

Comment: function gallery(e, change) {

  e.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('viewer').src = change.href;


}

Comment: <a href='images/chicks.jpg' onclick="gallery(e, this);"><img src='images/chicks-thumb.jpg'/></a>